# Reference needed for Hilbert-Schmidt result regarding basis of $V \subset H$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

I am seeking a reference that says:

> If $V \subset H \subset V^*$ is a Gelfand triple with all spaces Hilbert spaces and if $V \subset H$ is a compact embedding, then there is a basis of $V$ which is orthogonal wrt. $V$ and orthonormal wrt. $H$.

I know how to prove but I just want something to cite. Anyone have any ideas? I tried the usual sources but had no luck.

Comment: Can't you just write something like "the Hilbert-Schmidt representation of the compact embedding gives a common orthonogal basis"? References to the Hilbert-Schmidt representation theorem are easily available.

Comment: OK, I just wanted to provide link for some readers but maybe I can just write it.